# How to display/ read an '.off' (object file format) file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graphics, 3d, computer-vision

I have few .off files which I need to read and then display.
Though I found the code to read it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5355-toolbox-graph/content/toolbox_graph/read_off.m), but I could not display it now.

How can I display/ see these objects stored in .off format in MATLAB?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
[vert,fac]=read_off(filename)
patch('Faces',fac,'Vertices',vert)
```